# How to do this request using sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I would like to know the code to write to execute this request using sequelize:

```sql
select * from "Songs" 
where Id in (
    select "songId" from "Likes"
    where "userId"=1
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finaly found by myself how to do it, here is my code :

```js
  const songs = await models.Songs.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'title', 'imageUrl', 'nbListening'],
    where: {
      id: {
        [Op.in]: sequelize.literal(
          `(select "songId" from "Likes" where "userId"=${req.user.id})`
        ),
      },
    },
```